# Playing sound in Apple Watchkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to play a sound through the watchkit extension using WKAudioFilePlayer however no sound gets played. I'm using the haptic feedback code as a sort of debug to be sure it executes it (which it does). As a side note, mute is not on and the filename is correct.

```
NSURL *falcon = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                        pathForResource:@"falcon"
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];
WKAudioFileAsset *asset = [WKAudioFileAsset assetWithURL:falcon];
WKAudioFilePlayerItem *sound = [WKAudioFilePlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
audioPlayer = [WKAudioFilePlayer playerWithPlayerItem:sound];


[audioPlayer play];

WKInterfaceDevice *device = [WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice];
[device playHaptic:WKHapticTypeClick];
```

Comment: Is the file target membership set to your watch kit extension? It wont play if the membership is set to your app.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find out, however the file has been copied to within the watchkit extension. I'm not able to debug it either, beta 1 seems to have issues with loading a debug session.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I implemented as follows and it worked fine. (Sorry, it's Swift)

1) Define a property for the player object

```
var player: WKAudioFilePlayer!
```

2) Setup the asset and player when it's awaking

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("se_tap", ofType: "m4a")!
    let fileUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
    let asset = WKAudioFileAsset(URL: fileUrl)
    let playerItem = WKAudioFilePlayerItem(asset: asset)
    player = WKAudioFilePlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
}
```

3) Play **if the player is ready to play**.

```
@IBAction func playBtnTapped() {
    switch player.status {
    case .ReadyToPlay:
        player.play()
    case .Failed:
        print("failed")
    case .Unknown:
        print("unknown")
    }
}
```

In addition, it needed to connect a **Bluetooth Headset** with watch.

Comment: I've laid it out the same as you in Obj-c. I get the same notification for a bluetooth headset when using the simulator, however when running on an actual watch it just crashes the app and closes after a few seconds. It seems as though this is the method for playing music, I simply want to play a custom notification sound on the watch.

Comment: I tried it, and the sound is only played once. And it only works with bluetooth headset.

Comment: Please, how to implement streaming radio playback on a Watch App?

Comment: @Markus are you able to find how to play  streaming Watch App