# Play sound with WatchKit 2

Tags: ios, audio, watchkit

I have tried this - with the sound file ShipBullet.m4a in the Watch App and Extensions (to make sure that it can be found):

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("ShipBullet", withExtension:"m4a") {
    let asset = WKAudioFileAsset(URL:url)
    let sound = WKAudioFilePlayerItem(asset:asset)
    audioPlayer = WKAudioFilePlayer(playerItem:sound)
}

audioPlayer.play()
```

However, audioPlayer is always nil and no sound is played. Why? Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing sound in Apple Watchkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744166/playing-sound-in-apple-watchkit)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this reply to the same question I asked. [Play sound on Watchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30790883/2252407)

Let me know how you get on, I can't seem to get any sound to play on the watch itself however on the simulator it asks for a bluetooth headset.

Comment: I tried, can't get it to work on real devices. Do you have better luck now?

Comment: Here' what I found: 1) it will only works with Bluetooth device, if not, playing the sound will freeze the UI, 2) the sound will only play once. Attempting to play again will not be ready.