# Can declare WKAudioFileAsset in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm making an function to play sound in Apple Watch. I have found an question with same problem in this link: [Playing sound in Apple Watchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744166/playing-sound-in-apple-watchkit), but its Swift code.
In Objective-C I can't declare a variable with WKAudioFileAsset. Its easy when declare in Swift like this: `var player: WKAudioFilePlayer!`. I don't know how to use this class with Objective-C code. When type its in my code, doesn't see any tooltip suggestion. This is my code:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
[super awakeWithContext:context];

[self.wkButtonGroup setBackgroundImageNamed:@"parts_voice_recog01.png"];
[self.wkButtonGroup startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 16) duration:1 repeatCount:0];
// Configure interface objects here.

NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL* fileUrl = [myBundle URLForResource:@"bird" withExtension:@"wav"];
//    [[WKAudioFilePlayer playerWithPlayerItem:[WKAudioFilePlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:[WKAudioFileAsset assetWithURL:fileUrl]]] play];

WKAudioFileAsset *asset = [WKAudioFileAsset assetWithURL:fileUrl];
WKAudioFilePlayerItem *item = [WKAudioFilePlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
WKAudioFilePlayer *player = [WKAudioFilePlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
[player play];
```

}
Its have an bug occurs and its say: Use of declared indentifier 'WKAudioFileAsset' & 'WKAudioFilePlayer'. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

finally I found where's my mistake. This issue occurs cause I've ticked iphone version (don't know correct name of it) in **Target Membership** like this picture below:
[image]

When remove it from all .m file in Watch extension, my code run properly.
Home my answer will help someone face this problem.