# swift: How do I get an asset from the asset catalog

Tags: swift, watchkit, assets

Using WatchKit, when trying

```
  let asset = NSDataAsset(name:"ASSET-NAME")
```

XCode throws the following error `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSDataAsset'`

So how do I get a (sound) file from the asset catalog using WatchKit?

Comment: You are trying to use an iOS SDK item instead you need to use a WatchKit equivalent. [watchKit/AudioFile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkaudiofileasset)

Comment: But what’s the ‘url’ mentioned in the documentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30790883/5804550) you can get your audio file with

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "m4a")!
let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
let asset = WKAudioFileAsset(URL: fileUrl)
```

Comment: Do I have to place the file in the app directory, the [app name] extension directory or in the asset catalog?

Comment: The file must be part of your app bundle (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle) not your asset catalog. It is not important, if it is in the directory structure of the host app or the extension, but the file must be member of the extension target. You can configure this in the "Target Membership" part of the file inspector of the file.

Comment: Xcode changes it to let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "m4a")!
        let fileUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)
        let asset = WKAudioFileAsset(url: fileUrl)

Comment: Ah, sure, this is the new Swift syntax. Thank you, I fixed my answer.

Comment: When running, Xcode throws this error ( "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)") at "let filepath =.... "

Comment: If this fails, the file cannot be found. Maybe it is not member of the target.